# Rust generics: Expected <T> found <Foo>

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to use generics but I don't master that topic well enough and I get this error:

```
error: mismatched types:
expected `book::mdbook::MDBook<R>`,
found `book::mdbook::MDBook<renderer::html_handlebars::HtmlHandlebars>`
(expected type parameter,
found struct `renderer::html_handlebars::HtmlHandlebars`) [E0308]
```

This is the relevant code

```rust
pub struct MDBook<R> where R: Renderer {
    title: String,
    author: String,
    config: BookConfig,
    pub content: Vec<BookItem>,
    renderer: R,
}

impl<R> MDBook<R> where R: Renderer {

    pub fn new(path: &PathBuf) -> Self {

        MDBook {
            title: String::from(""),
            author: String::from(""),
            content: vec![],
            config: BookConfig::new()
                        .set_src(path.join("src"))
                        .set_dest(path.join("book")),
            renderer: HtmlHandlebars::new(), // <---- ERROR HERE
        }
    }
}
```

The `Renderer` trait is empty at the moment and the implementation for `HtmlHandlebars` is

```rust
pub struct HtmlHandlebars;

impl Renderer for HtmlHandlebars {

}

impl HtmlHandlebars {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        HtmlHandlebars
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, `&PathBuf` is as useless as `&String` is. You want `&Path` (the moral equivalent of `&str`).

Comment: Ok thanks! I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
impl<R> MDBook<R> where R: Renderer {

    pub fn new(path: &PathBuf) -> Self {
```

These lines claim that *for all* types `R` that implement `Renderer`, there is a method `new(path)` that returns `MDBook<R>`. However, your implementation of the method always returns `MDBook<HtmlHandlebars>` regardless of what `R` is.

You could add a trait bound to `R` (or a method to `Renderer`) that allows constructing a value of type `R` in `new`. Alternatively, the method could accept the renderer as parameter, i.e. `fn new(path: &Path, renderer: R) -> Self`. Either way, you need a way to get your hands on a renderer (i.e., a value of type `R`) inside `new`.

If on the other hand you want to support something like this:

```
let book = MDBook::new(path);
if some_condition {
    book.set_renderer(SomeOtherThing::new());
}
```

then generics are the wrong tool for the job, since they make the choice of renderer part of the static type of `book`. You can remove the `R` type parameter completely, keep your trait and simply store a [trait object](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html) (likely `Box<Renderer>`) in `MDBook`.

Comment: I want `new` to always return `MDBook<HtmlHandlebars>` because it's the default renderer. Should I change the return value from `Self` to `MDBook<HtmlHandlebars>` then?

Comment: Actually what I want to achieve is being able to swap out the Renderer for another. And traits seemed to be the best way to do it... Was that a good idea or is there a better way?

Comment: @MathieuDavid You can have a method that returns `MDBook<HtmlHandlebars>`, though it would be more appropriate to put that into an `impl MDBook<HtmlHandlebars> {}` block. However, if you don't have some other methods that do work with `MDBook<R>` for all `R`, then the generic is pointless. Also the name would have to be different, since there is no overloading here. Perhaps ask yourself why you want to make a special case for this default.

Comment: @MathieuDavid If you want to be able to have a `MDBook` object and change dynamically what renderer it uses, then generics are the wrong tool (though *traits* are good for that too). I've edited the answer to cover that as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, using `Box<Renderer>` works great.