# How to return a struct with a generic type that implements the `Read` and `Write` traits?

Tags: rust

I am trying to wrap a `TcpStream` and `TlsStream` in one object so that I can interface with either of them using one struct. I am trying to delegate the io methods to one or the other based on a config value but can't figure out how to return a struct with a generic type that implements the `Read` and `Write` traits

My code is as follows

```
pub struct TcpStream<T: Read + Write> {
    io_delegate: T,
    config: Config,
}

impl<T> TcpStream<T>
    where T: Read + Write
{
    pub fn connect<A: ToSocketAddrs>(config: Config, addr: A) -> io::Result<TcpStream<T>> {
        let tcp_stream = net::TcpStream::connect(addr).unwrap();
        if config.ssl {
            let tls_stream = TlsConnector::builder()
                .unwrap()
                .build()
                .unwrap()
                .connect("rem", tcp_stream)
                .unwrap();
            return Ok(TcpStream {
                          config: config,
                          io_delegate: tls_stream,
                      });
        }
        return Ok(TcpStream {
                      config: config,
                      io_delegate: tcp_stream,
                  });
    }
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following errors

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/rem/tcp_stream.rs:19:23
   |
19 |               return Ok(TcpStream {
   |  _______________________^ starting here...
20 | |                 config: config,
21 | |                 io_delegate: tls_stream
22 | |             });
   | |_____________^ ...ending here: expected type parameter, found struct `native_tls::TlsStream`
   |
   = note: expected type `rem::tcp_stream::TcpStream<T>`
              found type `rem::tcp_stream::TcpStream<native_tls::TlsStream<std::net::TcpStream>>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/rem/tcp_stream.rs:24:19
   |
24 |           return Ok(TcpStream{
   |  ___________________^ starting here...
25 | |                 config: config,
26 | |                 io_delegate: tcp_stream
27 | |         });
   | |_________^ ...ending here: expected type parameter, found struct `std::net::TcpStream`
   |
   = note: expected type `rem::tcp_stream::TcpStream<T>`
              found type `rem::tcp_stream::TcpStream<std::net::TcpStream>`
```

Is there a way to achieve this sort of thing?

Comment: If you are interested in returning a trait see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423

Comment: For your error see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490913/rust-generics-expected-t-found-foo

Comment: @Shepmaster OP is trying return a TlsStream in one branch and TcpStream in another branch, `impl Trait` is not going to help. The relation to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490913/rust-generics-expected-t-found-foo is quite subtle, while the answer does mention trait object, the question causing the error is different from this one.

Comment: @kennytm `impl Trait` is one of the *4* possibilities in the first answer; another being returning a boxed trait object. And returning a boxed trait object is what the OP did. I'm unclear; why you think it isn't a duplicate? And I don't see how the second question is not useful; it's the exact problem that OP is experiencing - the function says it returns any `T` that the caller picks, but the implementation ignores that and returns a concrete type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it does seem to work.

I created a new trait which is a combination of Read + Write then just stored it as a Box in my struct

```
trait ReadWrite : Read + Write {}

impl<T: Read + Write> ReadWrite for T {}

pub struct TcpStream{
    io_delegate : Box<ReadWrite>,
    config: Config
}

impl TcpStream {

    pub fn connect<A: ToSocketAddrs>(config: Config, addr: A) -> TcpStream {
        let tcp_stream = net::TcpStream::connect(addr).unwrap();
        if config.ssl {
            let tls_stream = TlsConnector::builder().unwrap().build().unwrap().connect("rem", tcp_stream).unwrap();
            return TcpStream {
                config: config,
                io_delegate: Box::new(tls_stream)
            };
        }
        return TcpStream{
                config: config,
                io_delegate:Box::new(tcp_stream)
        };
    }
}
```